# Theme translation on WordPress showing but file is damaged

Tags: php, wordpress, translation

I'm having a strange problem, 
a long time ago I translated my theme to another language and somewhere along the way the PO and MO files were damaged and it became a 0kb sized file. BUT! the website is still showing the translation and it seems like its working even though the translation file is damaged.

How do I extract the translation from my WordPress site when the translation file is worthless but somehow still translating.
any ideas?

Comment: If you have access to your cpanel, and if your server is backuped regularly you should be able to pull older backup copy with working .po and .mo files. I really can't think of other way to pull the translation out :\

Comment: i only have 30 days back and it seems it happend before. its sounds impossible that there is no way because the translation is showing... my website is translated... so the informations is coming from somewhere